# c# async without await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

In documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx it indicates that:

> If an async method doesn’t use an await operator to mark a suspension
>   point, the method executes as a synchronous method does, despite the
>   async modifier. The compiler issues a warning for such methods.

I believe this is the warning:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
>   Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls,
>   or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Then, in a different, referenced link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994635.aspx, the example it shows is as follows:

```
public class Example
{
    // ...
    private async void NextMove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => ComputeNextMove());
        // Update the UI with results
    }

    private async Task ComputeNextMove()
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Here, I'll **assume** that `ComputeNextMove` is basically a synchronous method, itself, not calling await.  That then would seem to contradict the issuance of a compiler warning (unless it's a bad example...)

If I'm not calling a .net Async method at the END of my asynchronous call stack, like `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` and I do want to implement some concrete "long running" synchronous logic, is there a more proper way to do it?

Perhaps my assumption is incorrect, and `ComputeNextMove` could be declared as `private void ComputeNextMove()` which would yield no warnings.

Comment: This is confusing.  You're calling `Task.Run(Func<Task>)`, which waits for the returned task.

Comment: The `Task` itself calls `await`.

Comment: "If code has async with no await, it's synchronous" - shows code with both: "I assume it is synchronous." I'm lost.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's just a bad example.

If `ComputeNextMove` is *truly* just a synchronous method which doesn't really do anything asynchronously (as the description suggests), it shouldn't be declared as `async`. It should instead be `private void ComputeNextMove()`.

`ComputeNextMove` will still execute on a background thread due to the use of `Task.Run`.

I would quite possibly use a method group conversion instead of a lambda expression here:

```
await Task.Run((Action) ComputeNextMove);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, it's probably a very silly question, but most examples I've seen show writing an async method that intrinsically calls a .net async method, and I was a little fuzzy on the case where _I_ might want to write such a method.  Based on the responses (and decompiling `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` as an example), it seems like it comes down to a Task somewhere that's awaited.

Comment: @Novox: It isn't always a task, although it usually is. And yes, relatively few people will will be writing their own "primitive" async methods. You usually end up going down - possibly via many other async methods - to framework *Async methods... or creating a task for specifically synchronous work that you just don't want to do on the current thread.

Comment: In your answer, you used method group coversion instead of a lamba expression. Why so ? Are there performance benefits for doing that?

Comment: @BilalFazlani: Nope, it was just a bit simpler.