# I can't read line-by-line from text file. How can I do?

Tags: c#, list, file, line, streamreader

After I got a file ( example: *a.txt*) from assests folder, while I'm reading this file line by line

this code part ( `line=reader.Readline()` ) have to read content of a file's line; but `line` is getting a file path.

I want to add all line in the file to list.(`lines`)

****** This project is about **Universal App** and **Windows Phone 8.1 part

```
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    public async void LoadFile(string file)
    {
        var InstallationFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
        var _file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(file);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You are not reading the file, you are reading the string you received as parameter. You are converting `file` string to a byte array, then you are reading this byte array

Comment: What is you project type?

Comment: how can i read a file ı saw this kind of example on the net

Comment: It would probably be better to name your parameter `fileName` and change the local variable `_file` to `fileContents`.  Then the error would be _very_ clear.

Comment: @DStanley ı will try and turn back :)

Answer (score 0):

you don't read the file with your `StreamReader`. try:

```
public async void LoadFile(string file)
    {          
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }  
    }
```

where `file` is your file path and name.

Comment: var InstallationFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
        var _file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(file);

Comment: [async without await?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707714/c-sharp-async-without-await) also wondered why you'd want to asynchronously load a file - would you use anything here to justify? [Using Async for File Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155757.aspx)

Comment: i look this page but ı dont use FileStream ı dont kmow why my System.IO  dont have File and FİleStream

Answer (score 0):

```
var InstallationFolder = await      Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var _file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync("a.txt");
var content = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(_file);
                        if (content.Contains(word))
                        {
                            lines.Add(word);   
                        }
```

i have written the code below according to your suggestions.However I got an error message like "**An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.
Additional information: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.
No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.**"

What should I do at this point to overcome this issue?